# Are the new users going through the FAQ of SO?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Most of new users, even existing users are not considering [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). Making of reputation does matter for some users here. But, the scope of SO is not only that.

So, What action should be taken into consideration for the new users must take a look at FAQ ?

Comment: You should read the faq

Comment: The scope of SO is not only reputation, but levelling up will happen. I know it bugs me that my SO rep has stalled (rarely find anything I can contribute recently). I remember something about setting things up to encourage the right kind of behaviour - there was something about some steps in Italy, I think - maybe a Joel Spolsky blog post. If someone's keeping score, people *will* seek to maximise their score, and on the Italian steps logic, it's the scoring that's to blame - not the people who do what people naturally do. The wording of the FAQ can only do so much to change that.

Answer (score 7):

You can answer your own question. Why didn't you read the FAQ?

> If you want to talk about the site
>   itself, please don't do it here. Visit
>   our [meta-discussion site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) where you can
>   talk about things like what questions
>   are appropriate, what tags we should
>   use, suggest a feature, or generally
>   discuss how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: Ahahahahahahaha! +1

Answer (score 3):

Noone is *required* to read the FAQ. You end up in the FAQ if you ask an unrelated question and users link to it, or if you are curious about the little link in the top row. Nowadays noone, *with respect to those who do*, reads the manual until something goes wrong.

Actually, it's almost better if you don't have to read the FAQ at all and instead find the site so intuitively to use that having questions like learning about how the reputation system works or how you can ask a question is already answered before you read about it.

Perhaps instead of *making* users read the FAQ, we can focus on why users don't follow the FAQ in the first place, and discuss improvements on the part on the site that users find dubious in regards to the topics discussed in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

How about knowing which type of Questions belong here

Answer (score 1):

From my observations, no.

Why? Well, duh: [users don't read](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html). "FAQ? What FAQ?"

Then you show them the condensed FAQ before posting, and you require them to check a box saying "yeah, I've read that". I imagine this internal monologue happens: "It's a bird! It's a plane! It's a wall of text spanning the entire screen! Quickly, what do I click to make it go away?!?" (it's probably more like "TL;DR, whatever.[click click]")

Comment: well, we do make new users sign a EULA before asking now (on SO only) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Yup. That's exactly the "wall of text" that I meant. Edited to clarify.